How to handle clickable command links in Telegram bot messages using Telegraf (Node.js)?
I'm building a Telegram bot using Node.js and Telegraf. I want to send messages with clickable HTML links that navigate users to different scenes when clicked.
Currently, I'm sending messages like this:
const message = `
Your assets
ABC Sell or buy
Amount: 173455050828209 SOL
Buy price: 1.0374
Current price: 1.0925
P/L: 0.0002 SOL`;


I want the "Sell or buy" text to be a clickable link that takes the user to a trade scene. What's the best way to implement this without using inline keyboards?
The most reliable way to implement clickable command links in Telegram bot messages is to use the bot's start command, here what i tried. but sometimes when i navigate to frequently links are becoming unresponsive.


const message = `
Your assets
ABC <a href="https://t.me/your_bot?start=trade_${encodeURIComponent(asset.name)}">Sell or buy</a>
Amount: ${asset.amount} SOL
Buy price: ${asset.buyPrice}
Current price: ${asset.currentPrice}
P/L: ${asset.pl} SOL
`;

ctx.reply(message, { parse_mode: 'HTML' });


bot.command('start', async (ctx) => {
  const param = ctx.message.text.split(' ')[1]; // gets trade_assetName'
  if (param && param.startsWith('trade_')) {
    const assetName = param.split('_')[1];
    await ctx.scene.enter('tradeScene', { asset: assetName });
  }
});



